# Como usar Scope_Identify para retornar id .NET

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, .net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e preciso que quando o sql faça o insert retorne o valor do id que foi inserido, estou usando o seguinte comando

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into solicitacoes (assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) values ('" + valorcadastro.assunto + "', '" + valorcadastro.mensagem + "', '" + valorcadastro.endereco + "','" + valorcadastro.anexo + "','Inicial', 0)", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Eu pesquisei em alguns tutoriais e achei a função Scope_Identify mas como devo implementar no meu código?

Answer (score 2):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` é uma função de SQL Server. Precisas da função equivalente para MySQL, `last_insert_id`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into solicitacoes (assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) values ('" + valorcadastro.assunto + "', '" + valorcadastro.mensagem + "', '" + valorcadastro.endereco + "','" + valorcadastro.anexo + "','Inicial', 0);SELECT last_insert_id()", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int ultimoRegistro = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Nota que precisas de usar `ExecuteScalar` em vez de `ExecuteNonQuery` para obter o valor retornado pela BD.

Ou então, se usares a classe `MySqlCommand`, podes aceder à propriedade `LastInsertedId`.

Nota que o teu comando está aberto a ataques por injecção de SQL. Devias usar queries parameterizadas:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into solicitacoes (assunto, mensagem, endereco, anexo, status, id_Departamento) values ('@assunto', '@mensagem', '@endereco','@anexo','Inicial', 0);SELECT last_insert_id()", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assunto", valorcadastro.assunto);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mensagem", valorcadastro.mensagem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", valorcadastro.endereco);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anexo", valorcadastro.anexo);
```

Comment: @Marconi [Funciona em MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: @Marconi ele deve ter visto tutoriais de SQL Server. Mas tagou a pergunta com `MySql`.

Comment: Que eu saiba não tem nenhum mecanismo ANSI SQL pra gerar chaves automaticamente; tem que fazer essa lógica RDBMS por RDBMS mesmo, a menos que você tope e.g. usar UUIDs como chaves, em qual caso eles podem ser gerados pelo próprio aplicativo.

Comment: Um pequeno alerta, penso que se houver escritas concorrentes a usar a mesma connection pode haver problemas. Pelo seguro o melhor é abrir sempre uma nova ligação ao executar um comando deste tipo e fechar de seguida.